# How to create Dynamic dropdown using an adjacency model in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, postgresql

I have an adjacency list table with an id, location and a parent_id in it. I created it knowing that it is the simplest way to create a dynamic category and subcategory dropdown list. I have been searching the net and SO for almost a week now for solutions but I find all of the solutions hard to comprehend as a beginning programmer. below is a sample of my table:

```
id  location             parent_id
1   Philippines 
2   Metro Manila        1
3   Abra                1
4   CALOOCAN CITY       2
5   CITY OF LAS PIÑAS   2
6   PILAR               3
7   SALLAPADAN          3
```

What I want is for a second dropdown to dynamically show the child(city) of any parent(province) that is selected. I was able to create a simple dropdown where it selects all parent names(provinces) under the parent_id: 1 but I don't know how to proceed with dynamically showing cities from there. I understand this has something to do with AJAX but i'm nowhere near from understanding it.

Below is my first dropdown that lists all parents(provinces):

```
= f.collection_select :location_id, Location.where("parent_id = 1"), :id, :name, { prompt: "Select a Location", class: 'form-control' }
```

I've been searching around for solutions however I do not understand most of them. any assistance on this matter will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you could articulate your actual question.  It seems to have something to do with the `locations` table but then you include a view which doesn't reference it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by referencing the list to itself in my model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :books
belongs_to :parent_location, class_name: Location
has_many :child_locations, class_name: Location, foreign_key: "parent_id"
```

end

then adding a grouped collection select in my form:

```
= f.collection_select :location_id, Location.where(parent_id: "1"), :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a Province"}, id: "province"
= f.grouped_collection_select :location_id, Location.all, :child_locations, :name, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a City/Municipality"}, id: "city"
```

then adding a jQuery that will show only the cities under the selected province in my js.cofee file:

```
jQuery ->
city = $('#city').html()
$('#province').select ->
    province = $('#province :selected').text()
    options = $(city).filter("optgroup[label='#{province}']").html()
    if options
        $('#city').html(options)
    else
        $('#city').empty()
```